# Copy files from mapped drive to local drive through Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, mapped-drive

On Windows Server, XCOPY/robocopy/copy from a mapped drive to a local drive works when executed in command prompt or batch.

E.g. z: mapped  drive:

```
xcopy z:\foldername\*.txt d:\test\
```

But the copy is not working in Task scheduler.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Commands run through Task Scheduler only have access to mapped drives if the task is executed with the option "Run only when user is logged on" enabled.

If enabling that option is not possible you have two other options. You can either modify your batch file to use UNC paths in place of the mapped drive letter, or add a **net use** command to the batch file to map the drive before accessing it, like this:

```
net use Z: \\server\share
```